# А что значит «коса»?

Tags: кавычки

Нужны кавычки?

`1. – Я косой косил травяно-сорняковый участок.`

`Я что значит «коса»?`

А здесь?

`2. – Я косой косил травяно-сорняковый участок.`

`Я что значит «косой»?`

Comment: косой - изогнутый, кривой, косоглазый, коса - изогнутое лезвие на палке для покоса травы. Кавычки нужны, когда речь идет о семантическом значении слова.